# Jmeter query about script recording

Tags: jmeter

please suggest how to identify that the script is right or not.[JMeter query image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9UZbZ.png)

please suggest me to identify that script is right or not

when I am recording script using JMeter recorder then in  that script i add suggested excludes still CSSs and other JS are showing in recording